Projecting Vectors (3D to 2D) Using Homogeneous Coordinates, With Known Camera Calibration
Suppose I have vectors in a 3D space (their starting points, dx, dy, and dz), and I would like to project them onto a camera, which I already have as a 3x4 projection matrix.
I can of course project the start points and end points in two passes. However, I am interested in only (dx, dy), not the starting point of a projected 2D vectors. Is there a way to compute their directly from (dx,dy,dz) of the 3D vector, perhaps using homogeneous coordinates in a different way? Thanks.

Your question is a bit difficult to grasp. I guess your point is: if I only know the vector (regardless of the starting and the ending point), can I project this direction vector from 3D to 2D? Namely, from $(\Delta X, \Delta Y, \Delta Z)$ to $(\Delta u, \Delta v)$. The answer is no, you must have the starting point for perspective projection. The following simple example can help you understand this:

The three cases above share the same $(\Delta X, \Delta Y, \Delta Z)$ but they have very different projected 2D vectors.
